# DIV won't show up over a DIV that's underneath it

Tags: css, wordpress, html, css-float, css-position

I can't figure out how to get a DIV to show up over a DIV that's underneath it.  In other words, my webpage has a head, with a DIV that floats left and a DIV that floats right.  Underneath that is a menu bar.  I don't have many menu items, so I want image in the DIV that floats right to partially overlap the menu bar.  I'm able to make it work with absolute positioning... but that not ideal.  I went ahead and changed the width of the menu bar, but that's more of a temporary fix to get what I want.  Thoughts?

www.sacspartans.org

```
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <div id="header-left">      
            <hgroup>
        <h1 class="site-title">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
            <img src="http://sacspartans.org/wp-        
                             content/uploads/2013/05/banner.png" alt="SacSpartans" 
                             title="SacSpartans" border="0" />
            </a>
        </h1>
        <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?> 
                    </h2>
            </hgroup>
    </div>  
    <div id="header-right"> 
        <img src="http://sacspartans.org/wp-
                    content/uploads/2013/05/california1.png" alt="MSU Alumni Club of 
                    the Sacramento Valley" title="MSU Alumni Club of the Sacramento  
                    Valley" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div id="navigation-bar">
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h3>
        <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 
                    'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to 
                    content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></a>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 
                    'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
    </nav>
    </div>
```

And now CSS info.

```
/* Header */
#header-left {
float: left;
}

#header-right {
float: right;
margin-top: 0;
}

#navigation-bar {
width: 575px;
}
```

Comment: Check out Z-index. Also, use relative position.

Comment: It's helpful if you create an example on jsfiddle.net because it makes it easier if we're all looking at and working on the same thing.

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not the PHP source.

Comment: can you explain it by a fiddle or a wireframe illustration?

Comment: I'm not familiar with jsfiddle.net. Or how to post the rendered HTML.  Looks like I'm gonna stick with what I have since I can't figure this out, haha.